# Std::copy fails in debug build

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code which throws out of bounds exception in debug build but works correctly in release build

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
std::array<uint, 4> expArray = {51,639,398,744};
unsigned dataArraySize = sizeof(expArray) / sizeof(uint) ;
std::vector<uint> expected ;
std::copy(&expArray[0], &expArray[dataArraySize], back_inserter(expected));
```

Comment: Debug build!? Where `sizeof(expArray) / sizeof(uint)` may be incorrect!? I wonder.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes debug build ...I get 4

Comment: so you are accessing out of bounds? `expArray` has valid indices from 0 to 3

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes I agree ..but if I try dataArraySize-1 the std::copy is copying only 3 elements to the vector

Comment: Works fine on my platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with just use the standard library as intended:

```
std::vector<uint> expected(begin(expArray), end(expArray));
```

The sad truth is that `sizeof(std::array<uint, 4>) == sizeof(uint[4])` doesn't have to hold. So you can't calculate the size as you would for a regular c-style array.

If you want the changes to your code to be minimal, either use `expArray::size()` or `std::tuple_size<decltype(expArray)>::value`

Answer (score 1):

Use `begin()` and `end()` methods instead of raw pointers. And if you want to get size of container use `size()` method.

```
std::array<uint, 4> expArray = {51,639,398,744};
std::vector<uint> expected;
std::copy(expArray.begin(), expArray.end(), back_inserter(expected));
```

or easier method (which doesnt suit every situation)

```
std::vector<uint> expected(std::begin(expArray), std::end(expArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
 unsigned dataArraySize = sizeof(expArray) / sizeof(uint) ;
```

should be:

```
std::size_t dataArraySize = std::tuple_size<decltype(expArray)>::value;
```